# Python keeping count of totals based on user input

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a function in my item ordering system where the goal is to keep totals of how many items were ordered and print each item  and the amount they were ordered

```
class Totals(object):

def __init__(self, total):
    self.total = total

def total(order_amount, coffee_id):
    count = 0
    print("Coffee Type\t\tAmount of Times ordered")                       
    print("-----------\t\t-----------------------")
    for coffee in coffee_available:

        if coffee.coffee_id == coffee_id:
            count = order_amount
            coffee_id = order_coffee

            print("{}\t- - -\t {} ".format(coffee.coffee_type, count))
```

With this I can only print one item and it does show how many of that item is ordered but again it only does this to one item

The function is based on user input and the items are

```
coffee_available=[Coffee(1, "1: Flat White", 3.50), 
                  Coffee(2, "2: Long Black", 3.50), 
                  Coffee(3, "3: Cappuccino", 4.00), 
                  Coffee(4, "4: Espresso", 3.25), 
                  Coffee(5, "5: Latte", 3.50)]
```

how do I change the function so that it prints all items and keeps track of the amount of items ordered each time it is called so that after my code is looped through multiple times it still displays each item and the amount of times it was ordered

---

Ok now I have a method that prints each of the types of coffee but prints the amount of coffee ordered for 1 item to all of the items and it does not retain the amount of coffee ordered for each item as is needed

```
 class Order(object):

def __init__(self):
    self.total = {}

def order(self, order_amount, coffee_id):
    if coffee_id not in self.total.keys():
        self.total[coffee_id] = 0
    self.total[coffee_id] += order_amount


def print_order(self, coffee_id):
    print(" ")
    print("Coffee Type\t\tAmount of Times ordered")                       
    print("-----------\t\t-----------------------")
    for coffee in coffee_available:
        print("{}\t- - -\t {} ".format(coffee.coffee_type, self.total[coffee_id]))
```

and this is how I call it

```
        new_order = Order()
        new_order.order(order_amount, coffee_available[order_coffee - 1])
        new_order.print_order(coffee_available[order_coffee - 1])
```

any suggestions would be great

Comment: The problem is more your function looks like it's designed to only print one type of coffee. You should pass in as a parameter the actual order instead. Eg a list of Coffee objects that have been selected. order_amount and coffee_id look to only be integers which doesn't get you very far.

Comment: Please follow https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=o9pEzgHorH0

Answer (score 2):

You should save a dictionary that map from the coffee id to it amount of orders and update it on each order.

```
class Totals(object):

    def __init__(self):
        self.total = {}

    def order(self, order_amount, coffee_id):
        if coffee_id not in self.total.keys():
            self.total[coffee_id] = 0
        self.total[coffee_id] += order_amount
```

For the printing you should add a print function that print `self.total` as you wish.

Comment: so my understanding of this code is that you define a function that takes parameters order_amount and coffee_id. You loop through the coffee_available array and you match coffee_id with what the user inputs. Then you say that if coffee_id  does not match anything in self.total.keys() you make self.total[coffee_id] = 0, otherwise you just += order_amount. What I'm a bit confused with is what the self.total = {} is at the start and why you += order_amount to self.total[coffee_id]. Just want to make sure I fully understand this

Comment: @killerstick1 self.total is dictionary that map coffee to the amount of orders. At the start the dict is empty, hence the `self.total = {}` initializtion. If no order of this coffee_id placed yet you insert it by `self.total[coffee_id] = 0` and then also (**not else**) update the amount by the current order

Comment: The lines `for coffee in coffee_available:` and `if coffee.coffee_id == coffee_id:` are not doing much here. They're pretty much equivalent to "if there is a coffee with this id". Do you need that, or is this already sanitised elsewhere first? (I realise that they're carried over from the original code example, just questioning whether we can ditch them).

Comment: @nimasmi you right. I just copy and paste, updating the answer

Comment: ok and to print the total for each coffee would I do what I did above and loop through coffee_available and print the coffee_type and self.total[coffee_id]? The code also comes up with an error saying self in self.total.keys(): isnt defined

Comment: @killerstick1 exactly. I fixed the self problem

Comment: @OhadEytan so I made my function to print the totals of each coffee ordered as is above but unfortunately it prints the amount ordered for 1 coffee to all of the coffees. Are the parameters im using correct when I call the order method? order_amount and coffee_available[order_coffee - 1]

Comment: @killerstick1 It's hard to tell what went wrong, you can update your question with the updated code.

Answer (score 0):

This is personally how I believe you should manage the items ordered. This example has a dictionary mapping a Coffee object to the number of times it was ordered.

```
class Order(object):
    ID = 0
    def __init__(self):
        self._orders = {}
        self._order_id = Order.ID
        Order.ID += 1

    def add_item(self, coffee):
        # Gets the current quantity for the coffee
        # If no previous order qty defaults to 1
        qty = self._orders.get(coffee, 1)
        # Add / update dict with coffee object and qty
        self._orders[coffee] = qty

    def display_order(self):
        print("Coffee Type\t\tAmount of Times ordered")                       
        print("-----------\t\t-----------------------")
        # For each coffee object ordered | sorted by coffee id
        for coffee in sorted(self._orders, key = lambda item: item.coffee_id):
            print("{:<10}\t- - -\t {} ".format(coffee.coffee_type,
                                               coffee.price * self._orders[coffee]))
```

Comment: im kinda confused what do i put in the parameter of Order.add_item() when I want to call it? and do I need to put any parameters for Order.display_order?

Comment: The way I see it is that each Order object contains Coffee objects selected by the user eg `o = Order(); o.add_item(coffee_available[0])` to add a flat white. `o.display_order()` would be all you need to display the info. You may not need it as a class though depends on the rest of your code. This was more my interpretation of managing the items without seeing all your code.